# Markdown to PDF Converstion with Pandoc: Make pages a specific size, in inches

Tags: pdf, latex, markdown, pandoc

So I know you can use `pagesize` and `geometry` to set the page size of the PDFs Pandoc makes to presets (like a5, b5, etc), but is there a way to set a precise pair of dimensions? I'm going to be using the PDF with Amazon Self-Publishing (paperback) and I need the pages to be exactly 5x8in, as that's the closest setting KDP has to what I want. Thank you!

Comment: 5 \times 8 what? Units would be useful ...

Comment: lmao sorry, inches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set an arbitrary page size via `papersize="{5in,8in}"`

```
pandoc -V geometry:papersize="{5in,8in}" test.md -o out.pdf
```

For more options, see the geometry package documentation: https://texdoc.org/serve/geometry.pdf/0